# Loading an external web site in Xwalkview Crosswalk Project for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, whitelist, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am trying to build an iOS app that simply loads a website where our WebRTC application resides. I tried to follow the [Crosswalk Hybrid Application for iOS](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios/quick_start_guide.html) quick start guide. The application build sucessfully, but when using `window.open('https://www.<website>.am', '_self');` function I get error in the XCode console saying that whitelisting has failed. How do I whitelist an origin for the Crosswalk project?